# Display Self-Service fields on Contact Object

Tags: trigger, user-record, contact, portal

I would like to display Self-Service Portal fields on the contact object. I need the fields "IsActive" and "Last Login". Is it possible by trigger?

Comment: What do you mean "is it possible by trigger"? what does the trigger have to do with page layout of SSP? I think some more research by you, can provide with a clearer question, so we can answer.

Comment: I Want to be able to display these fields on the contact and case page layouts, so that I'll have indication if the case is related to a SSP user and what's his last login date to the portal.

Comment: I know I can create a joint report of contact (SSP data is there) and cases, but I want to be able to see this info on the case layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce already provides a way to see if a case is related to a self-service user. In the self-service portal settings you can select a case origin (the default is 'web') and as long as this is unique you know that any cases with that origin were created from the SSP.

Furthermore, there is a 'visible in SSP' field on the case that tells you if SSP users can see the case and comment on it (and their comments will show up in the case comments related list).

There is no built-in way to see if the related SSP user is active or their last login date directly on the case but the contact does have a "view self-service user" button so it would be two clicks from the case detail page to get to this information.

If you need this right on the case detail page you will need to be an inline VF page similar to what @mohith wrote but it should be on the SelfServiceUser NOT User like he has it.

visalforce page:

```
   <apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="stampLoginDetailsforPortalUser">
  <apex:pageMessages />
  <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!loginInfo.size >0}">
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!loginInfo}" var="a">

 <apex:column headerValue="Last Login" value="{!a.LastLoginDate}"/>
  <apex:column headerValue="IsActive" value="{!a.IsActive}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:page>
```

controller:

```
public with sharing  class stampLoginDetailsforPortalUser {
    private Case UserCase;

    public stampLoginDetailsforPortalUser(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        Case temp = (Case) stdController.getRecord();
            this.UserCase = [select contactID from Case where ID = :temp.ID];
    }

    public List<User> getloginInfo(){
        List<User> us=[Select Id,LastLoginDate,IsActive,ContactId from SelfServiceUser where ContactId=:UserCase.ContactId];

        if(us.size()==0){
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,  'Login for self service portal user not enabled'));
        }

        return us;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great! however, if it's a visualforce page (not fields populated), can I display it on cases? so if there is a contact assosicated with the case, I'll have a visualforce section that displays if it's active and what's he's last login

Comment: @ItayB When a VF page uses the standard controller you can add it as an inline vf page on that objects page layout. If you want this to show up on the Case detail page rather than the contact detail page you would have to change the standard controller to Case instead of Contact and modify the controller and queries slightly.

Comment: Could you modify your controller accordingly?

Comment: getting the following error message on the case page layout (where I placed the VF page): Content cannot be displayed: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Case.ContactId

Comment: @ItayB I changed the controller in the answer. please try it now.

Comment: wonderful, thanks! Do you have any examples of how should I write test coverage to this controller?

Comment: @itayb You might want to search for other Stack exchange questions on how to test vf controllers.

Comment: My concern is with the Self-service user creation (on the test coverage), as I'm not allowed to do so on apex. Not sure what do to, can I reference to a specific record??